# What is the meaning of "+" in crontab file and why it works?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've found this cron command on some Ubuntu server in `/etc/cron.d/`.

`0 */3+2 * * *    root <command goes here>`

Tried this on my PC with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS by adding the following file:
/etc/cron.d/test

`*/3+2 * * * *    root echo 'Cron test'`

Here is the cron log:

`Oct 20 03:51:01 artem-notebook CRON[17427]: (root) CMD (echo 'Cron test')
Oct 20 03:54:01 artem-notebook CRON[17595]: (root) CMD (echo 'Cron test')
Oct 20 03:57:01 artem-notebook CRON[17662]: (root) CMD (echo 'Cron test')
Oct 20 04:00:01 artem-notebook CRON[17728]: (root) CMD (echo 'Cron test')`

So it seems it works somehow, right?

What does this "+" mean? Is there any documentation for this feature?

Comment: `This cron`? What is the name of the file?

Comment: Works on mine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cron` do not support any arithmetics within fields. Dashes means ranges (`9-12` = `9,10,11,12`) and slashes means "each Nth". It's look like parser simply ignore everything from the unparsed char to the end. So `*/3+2` is equivalent to `*/3` that in turn is equivalent to `0,3,6,9,12,15...48,51,54,57` - exactly what you have in your logs.

Comment: Looks like.  I'm checking the code now to verify that assumption